# Xpath return nav/ul/li/a/herf

Tags: c#, xpath, selectsinglenode

the website URL: www.tase.co.il

the website source code:

```
<nav class="collapse more_madad_nav in" id="more_madad_nav">
    <ul class="first_level">
        <li>
            <ul class="second_level">
                <li class="current"><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/major_data"> x </a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/graph"> x </a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/indices">x</a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/statistics"> x</a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/historical_data"> x </a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/otc"> x </a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/security/1158823/short_sale">x</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><!----><h3> x </h3>
            <ul class="second_level">
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/company/2135/about?securityId=1158823">x</a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/company/2135/securities?securityId=1158823">x</a></li>
                <li><!----><a href="/he/market_data/company/2135/reports_maya?securityId=1158823">x</a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/company/2135/financial_reports?securityId=1158823">x</a></li>
                <li><a href="/he/market_data/company/2135/analysis?securityId=1158823">x</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

my C# code for GetHtmlDocument:

```
protected HtmlDocument GetHtmlDocument(string sUrl, Encoding oEncoding, bool bSetContentType = true) {

    string sPostData = "GET";
    string sReferer = string.Empty;
    List < string > oCookies = new List < string > ();
    string sHtmlContent = string.Empty;
    string sRedirectUrl = string.Empty;
    return GetHtmlDocument(sUrl, sPostData, sReferer, oCookies, ContentType.html, out sRedirectUrl, out sHtmlContent, oEncoding, bSetContentType);
}

protected HtmlDocument GetHtmlDocument(string sUrl, string sPostData, string sReferer, List < string > oCookies, ContentType eContentType, out string sRedirectUrl, out string sHtmlContent, Encoding oEncoding, bool bSetContentType = true) {

    HttpStatusCode oHttpStatusCode = SingleHttpRequest(sUrl, sPostData, sReferer, oCookies, ContentType.html, out sRedirectUrl, out sHtmlContent, oEncoding, true, bSetContentType);
    if (oHttpStatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        string sMsg = string.Format("SingleHttpRequest to '{0}' returned '{1}' status", sUrl, oHttpStatusCode);
        LOG.Error(sMsg);
        throw new Exception(sMsg);
    }
    HtmlDocument oHtmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    LOG.DebugFormat("sHtmlContent : \n{0}\n , sUrl : {1}", sHtmlContent, sUrl);
    oHtmlDocument.LoadHtml(sHtmlContent);
    return oHtmlDocument;
}

HtmlDocument oSearchHtmlDocument = GetHtmlDocument(sSearchUrl, false);
HtmlNode o = oSearchHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='more_madad_nav']//ul[@class='second_level']//li/a[contains(@href,'about')]/@href"); //this is the line!
```

I'm trying to get the first href from the "second level"(/he/market_data/company/2135/about?securityId=1158823)
Thanks for the help

Comment: Try Query like `nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/@href `

Answer (score 0):

Try Query `nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/@href`

See Testing result below
[image]

Comment: I'm using this:
  HtmlNode o = oSearchHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/@href");

looks fine to you?

Comment: One line code is not enough. Please show full c# code

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath

```
//*[@id='more_madad_nav']//ul[@class='second_level']//li/a[contains(@href,'about')]
```

Demo:

[image]

**UPdate**
To get the attribute value in C#

```
string element  = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("/*[@id='more_madad_nav']/ul[@class='first_level']//ul[@class='second_level']//li/a[contanins(@href,'about')]")).GetAttribute("href");
```

Comment: It seems that it works but in the code I write using C # it doesn't work.

Comment: still not working,
Did you manage to do this in the IDE and not through the INSPECT of the browser?
Because I send a get request to the URL and inside the body tag I don't see all the tags (elements that i should see inside the body tag)
I can see all the elements only  through the INSPECT.